# Difflib.SequenceMatcher not working in "IF" Statement?

Tags: python, fuzzy-search, difflib, sequencematcher

I am executing a code with SequenceMatcher (Difflib library) nested in an "IF" Statement like this:

'''

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

string_one = 'He is right'
string_two = 'He was right'

print("It returns a ratio", SequenceMatcher(a=string_one,b=string_two).ratio())
if(SequenceMatcher(a=string_one,b=string_two).ratio()>=60):
    print("It does not return a ratio", SequenceMatcher(a=string_one,b=string_two).ratio())
```

'''

The first Sequence Matcher (Before the If statement) returns a ratio, but the second one (Inside the "If" Statement) does not return a ratio.

Can any

Comment: The result of the `.ratio()` method is about 0.9 with your two strings.  This is not greater than or equal to 60, so the `if` statement body does not execute.

Comment: Oh man I am tired, I did not realize it. I have been wondering about it for hours.

Thank you